# Unable to connect to LDAP server after some connection in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap, connection-string

I have a MVC application, in which I am using LDAP connection to authenticate user. The issue which I am facing is after every 5th or 6th connection, user is getting an error message.
"*An error occurred during processing of a configuration file required to service the request. Please review the specific error below and modify your connection properly*"

Is there any limitation in LDAP server or do I need to set some limitation somewhere?
[

```html
<membership defaultProvider="MY_ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MY_ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConn" attributeMapUsername="********"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gucmj.png)